# Where do the gear ratio and rotor inertia values in the iiwa sdf come from?

Tags: drake, urdf

Upon examining the [sdf file](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/sdf/iiwa14_no_collision.sdf) (and urdf) for the iiwa14 in drake, I see there are values for the gear ratio and rotor inertia of each joint, for example in lines 83-86.

```
      </axis>
      <drake:gear_ratio>160.0</drake:gear_ratio>
      <drake:rotor_inertia>0.0001321</drake:rotor_inertia>
    </joint>
```

I see the ratios are the same as [the LWR3](https://www.dlr.de/rm/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-12464/21732_read-49777/) which makes sense, as it was a precursor to the iiwa. However, I assume that there is some other source available for the iiwa specifically?

I could not find the rotor inertias, after checking [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/15613) and subsequently [here](https://github.com/IFL-CAMP/iiwa_stack/tree/2fa5bd5?tab=readme-ov-file).

Where does this information come from? I haven't been able to find it straight from KUKA, or any other source.

*Also in simulations such as the [passive iiwa simulations (example 2.2)](https://manipulation.csail.mit.edu/robot.html#section2), are the reflected inertia effects included by default?*

**Edit**
Re: question 2, it seems the reflected inertia is included in the mass matrix calculation by default, based on the [documentation for CalcMassMatrix()](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#adf95c4544e8855015c110ba173ccdd0b)

Answer (score 0):

I think the [README](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/manipulation/models/iiwa_description/README.md) has the answer:

---

The rotor inertias and gear ratios are estimated based on the specifications of a similar robot, i.e. DLR LWR III (link below). The motors and gears are assumed to be the RoboDrive ILM series and Harmonic Drive CSG series. These values are being validated experimentally.

"DLR LWR III. (URL: https://www.dlr.de/rm/en/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-12464/21732_read-49777/, Accessed on 2023-05-08)

---

If you look at the git history for that README and the URDF files, you might find additional discussion in the GitHub pull requests that made the changes.